# Node.js async.each didn't call callback function

Tags: node.js, async.js

I met some problems in aysnc function in node.js. Below is my code:

```
let async = require("async");
let list1 = {
  "aaa": true,
  "bbb": true
}
let list2 = [{
  "name": "aaa"
}, {
  "name": "bbb"
}];
let flag = true;
let i = 0;
async.each(list2, function (activity, callback) {
  if (!list1[activity['name']]) {
    flag = false;
  }
  i++;
  if (i === list2.length) {
    callback(null);
  //callback("error");
  }
}, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log("completed callback");
  //need the value of flag to execute my business logic 
});
```

If the values are all `true` in list1, the value of flag will be `true`, and I will execute my business logic on the basis of the flag. And I also set an `i` to judge if it is the last loop, all the loop finish executing, I want to call the callback. But something strange happened, if I set `callback("error");` I could call the final callback. If I set `callback(null);`, I couldn't call the final callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your flag variable in your callback since it will be in scope, and you shouldn't need to manually call the callback at then end of the loop.

We'll call the callback with no parameter passed on each iteration as long as no error has occurred.

In this context it is safe to use flag in this way, since we will only set it to false when our logic requires it.

```
let async = require("async");

let list1 = {
    "aaa": true,
    "bbb": true
}
let list2 = [{
    "name": "aaa"
}, {
    "name": "bbb"
}];

// Assume flag is initally true.
let flag = true;
async.each(list2, function (activity, callback) {
    if (!list1[activity['name']]) {
        flag = false;
    }
    // Pass an error if it occurs.
    callback();

}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error occurred: ", err);
    } else {
        // You can use flag in your business logic now.
        console.log(`Completed callback: flag: ${flag}`);
    }
});
```